# ModX Revo Relative Path Images in Resource Editor

Tags: ckeditor, modx, modx-revolution

I have a site in ModX Revolution that I am having an issue with.  Well... ok, it's not an issue for me, but for my client it will definately be an issue.

The issue is, I am finding that when adding an image to a resource using the CKEditor plugin, the paths to the images are not site relative(they are being put in as assets/images/image.png, when it should be /assets/images/image.png).  Which of course will cause them to fail to load in when /page/YXZ is rendered.

I have searched all around, and I cannot find the answer to this seemingly impossible task...

How can I ensure that all files are relative to the site, without having to revert to `<base href="" />` tags?

## Note:

I cannot use `<base href>`, due to #identifier links throughout the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have "fixed" the issue by going with TinyMCE instead of CKEditor for this.  There are special settings in TinyMCE that allow me to set rootrelative links for images and files.

Answer (score 0):

You *should* be using `<base href="[[++site_url]]">` with MODX, or you'll run into all kinds of problems with url references (such as this one).

If you want to use anchor tags, you just need to modify the syntax slightly:

```
<a href="[[~[[*id]]]]#anchor">My Anchor Link</a>
```

http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/making-sites-with-modx/structuring-your-site/resources/named-anchor

**Note for others:** if you want to use friendly urls with a MODX site, the `<base href="">` tag is essential: http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/using-friendly-urls

Comment: Going through a few hundred pages to update links is out of the question.

Comment: So, in your case I would look at a find and replace in the database. Or check out the AnchorsAway plugin which replaces them at runtime: https://github.com/Cipa/AnchorsAway http://forums.modx.com/thread/30912/anchors-away-plugin-for-revo

Comment: Anchors are all used for other javascript effects in the site, why would I want or need to get rid of them?

Comment: I'm not talking about removing them - just prefixing them with the full page url so they work with MODX. Your MODX site has been set up incorrectly so this is the best solution I can think of to keep your anchors working when you add the `<base>` tag - which is needed so your relative image paths will work. It's a lot simpler than modding the CKEditor.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at the 'strip_image_paths' system variable under the file system group... you can set so that modx will rewrite them as either relative or absolute.

Comment: already tested, setting to yes, and to no... no difference.  I think it's something to do with the CKEditor configuration.  I was able to get it working properly via using TinyMCE and dumping CKEditor, but the client would really like to use CKEditor...

Answer (score -2):

You should still be able to use anchor links with the base href.